# Streaming Audio From Raspberry Pi 2 to Bluetooth Speaker

Tags: raspbian, audio, bluetooth, raspbian-jessie

I want to use bluetooth to stream any audio being played on my raspberry pi to my bluetooth speaker. I've installed bluez and all the other bluetooth packages. I can see and connect to my speaker, but I can't hear any audio.

Is there something else I need to do to send audio to the speaker from the raspberry pi?

Raspbian Jessie (not Noobs)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68779) post has a lengthy rundown on one approach. I'd post it as an answer, but it's *giant*.

Comment: You might also want to have a look [at these](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbluetooth%5D+audio+output+is%3Aquestion), which revolve around using pulseaudio -- I'm not sure if that's enabled on Raspbian by default (it is available though), plus it is a beast to use IMO, but it does tend to be the appropriate tool for this kind of thing I think.

Comment: @goobering I have intially followed those instructions. However when i try to install bluez-utils bluez-alsa it says they have been replaced with bluez. Furthermore, when I go to edit /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf, the file doesn't exist.

I think that is where i'm failing, no alsa?